# IndexError: list index out of range from rsplit output

Tags: python, strsplit, index-error

I have a list of filepaths in a master file

```
/home/tmp/dir1/file1.xml
/home/tmp/dir2/file2.xml
/home/tmp/dir2/file3.xml
```

I am trying to extract the names like "file1", "file2", "file3", without the `.xml` or the leading filepath

So in my code, I am doing something like:

```
for line in masterfile:
    fname = line.rsplit('/', 1) //e.g : [/home/tmp/dir1, file1.xml]
    fname_noext = (fname[1]).rsplit('.xml')
    print fname_noext[0]
```

I keep getting

`fname_noext = (fname[1]).rsplit('.xml')
IndexError: list index out of range`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I checked for trailing white space etc, doesn't look like there is anything there.

Comment: print `line` and `fname` and you will see what's wrong.

Comment: `['/home/tmp/dir1', 'file1.xml']` etc

Comment: No it's not a txt. It doesn't have an extension. So may be that's the issue?

Comment: Empty line at the end of the file?

Comment: @tobias_k bingo! Empty line at the end of the file! FML :|

Answer (score 2):

try to leverage os lib

```
import os
for line in masterfile:
    fname = os.path.basename(line )
    fname_noext, _ = os.path.splitext(fname )
    print fname_noext
```